# Why can't I write `List[I]` but can write 'I'

Tags: scala

In the following code, I can define `id` as `List[I]`

```
abstract trait Repository[I,M] {

    def getOneById(id: List[I]): Option[M]
}
```

But why I can't define `id` as `List[I]` in the following code?

```
abstract trait Repository[List[I],M] {

    def getOneById(id: List[I]): Option[M] //I get compiler error - cannot resolve I. Why?
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In

```
abstract trait Repository[List[I],M] {
    def getOneById(id: List[I]): Option[M]
}
```

`List` is the name of a *type parameter* which has nothing to do with the *type* `scala.Predef.List`. And `I` in `[List[I],M]` only means that this type parameter is itself a generic type accepting a single type parameter. This name `I` is only visible inside `List[I]`.

So this could be equally rewritten as

```
abstract trait Repository[F[_],M] {
    def getOneById(id: F[I]): Option[M]
}
```

which should make it clear why this doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you Alexey. Undersood.

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract trait Repository[I,M] {

    def getOneById(id: List[I]): Option[M] 
}
```

Should work. Basically in the trait definition you only list your typearguments while on the right hand side of id you need to specify a type. `List` is a typeconstructor accepting one argument in your case `I`

EDIT: See comment chain

Comment: sorry, I know that the first one will work. I am trying to understand why the second one doesn't because `List` is also a type, isn't it?

Comment: `List` is a typeconstructor `List[Int]` is a type. but that's nitpicky. the reason why it didn't work is because you can think of `... trait Repository[I, M]` like a `def repository` but for types. `[I,M]` just says that `Repository` accepts 2 type parameters called `I` and `M` thus the expression `List[I]` doesn't make much sense in that position. In the position as the function argument for `id` it makes sense because `id` has to be a `List` of whatever you pass as `I` into `Repository`

Comment: "the expression List[I] doesn't make much sense in that position" It does make perfect sense to the compiler, the problem is that the sense it makes is not the desired one.

Comment: ok i have to redact. i had to ask smarter people than me in gitter. basically you bind a typeparameter called list (nothing to do with  scala List) of kind * - > * and it's type parameter I. however I is not valid but could be used like this `trait Repository[F[I] <: List[I]] ` so it's only bound in the parameter brackets